# performance: find the index of max value in an arr(tie allowed)

Tags: c++, performance

Just as the title, and BTW, it's just out of curiosity and it's not a homework question. It might seem to be trivial for people of CS major. The problem is I would like to find the indices of max value in an array. Basically I have two approaches.

1. scan over and find the maximum, then scan twice to get the vector of indices
2. scan over and find the maximum, along this scan construct indices array and abandon if a better one is there.

May I now how should I weigh over these two approaches in terms of performance(mainly time complexity I suppose)? It is hard for me because I have even no idea what the worst case should be for the second approach! It's not a hard problem perse. But I just want to know how to approach this problem or how should I google this type of problem to get the answer.

Comment: Doing two or three operations in one loop, or doing two or three loops doing one operation each has the same time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

In term of complexity:

> scan over and find the maximum,
>   then scan twice to get the vector of indices

First scan is `O(n)`.
Second scan is `O(n)` + `k` insertions (with k, the number of max value)
`vector::push_back` has **amortized** complexity of `O(1)`.
so a total `O(2 * n + k)` which might be simplified to `O(n)` as `k <= n`

> scan over and find the maximum,
>   along this scan construct indices array and abandon if a better one is there.

Scan is `O(n)`.
Number of insertions is more complicated to compute.
Number of `clear` (and number of element cleared) is more complicated to compute too. (`clear`'s complexity would be less or equal to number of element removed)

But both have upper bound to `n`, so complexity is less or equal than `O(3 * n) = O(n)` but also greater than equal to `O(n)` (Scan) so it is `O(n)` too.

So for both methods, complexity is the same: `O(n)`.

For performance **timing**, as always, you have to measure.

Comment: what if I don't use `clear`, I just initialize a new one? Does that make the upper bound 2*n?

Comment: @Lihaonan: `O(n) == O(2*n)` so it is ok. As long as `O(a * MyClear(b))`  <= `O(a * b)` your are fine.

Answer (score 0):

For your first method, you can set a condition to add the index to the array. Whenever the max changes, you need to clear the array. You don't need to iterate twice.

For the second method, the implementation is easier. You just find max the first go. Then you find the indices that match on the second go.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a previous answer, complexity is O(n) in both cases, and measures are needed to compare performances.

However, I would like to add two points:

The first one is that the performance comparison may depend on the compiler, how optimisation is performed.

The second point is more critical: performance may depend on the input array.

For example, let us consider the corner case: `1,1,1, .., 1, 2`, i.e. a huge number of `1` followed by one `2`. With your second approach, you will create a huge temporary array of indices, to provide at the end an array of one element. It is possible at the end to redefine the size of the memory allocated to this array. However, I don't like the idea to create a temporary unnecessary huge vector, independently of the time performance concern. Note that such a array could suffer of several reallocations, which would impact time performance.

This is why in the general case, without any knowledge on the input, I would prefer your first approach, two scans. The situation could be different if you want to implement a function dedicated to a specific type of data.